How to support multiple SIMD architectures in one C++ application?
I'm writing an application in C++ and I want to use intrinsics for SIMD.
Now I want to write separate code for different architectures like SSE, AVX2 and AVX512.
I can check at run-time which hardware is supported and jump to the right implementation.
The problem is that the compiler needs to know about the architecture it compiles for. But I want to add implementations for different architectures.
How can I deal with that?
Can I add compiler options for different sections of the code?
I use Visual Studio Code with MSVC compiler. I do not want to use a SIMD library to be able to use SIMD operations that are not supported by the library.

On my project, for hardware specific routines we compile the same code multiple times for different hardware platforms, and then dynamically load that hardware platform specific code at runtime after determining the hardware platform being run upon.  (Some of the "same code" is actually a separate implementation using intrinsics.)

It's not entirely true that the compiler needs to know the architecture, for Clang and GCC it is more true, but MSVC lets you use intrinsics without specifying an ISA extension. That does tend to cost more vzeroupper and such extra nonsense.

But if the compiler does not know the hardware, how can it use the associated SIMD registers?

Because you told it to (by using SIMD intrinsics, which don't require compiling with the associated /ARCH), but that doesn't allow the compiler to use those feature on its own accord (which the associated /ARCH does allow). GCC and Clang don't work that way.

Why would that cost more vzeroupper instructions?

This is somewhat involved, but the architecture has to be known at compile time (the specific ISA extensions need not). So you may start with including the right headers. If you plan to include additional compilers or architectures, add more #elifs
#if defined(_MSVC_LANG) && defined(_M_ARM64)
    #include <arm64_neon.h>
    #define ARCH_ARM64
#elif defined(_MSVC_LANG) && defined(_M_X64)
    #include <intrin.h>
    #define ARCH_X64
#else
    // TODO: Add support for other architectures
    #error "Unsupported architecture"
#endif

Then we can add code that detects CPU capabilites and stores them, so we do not have to query at every use.
enum class isa_lvl: unsigned int
{
    none = 0,
    sse2 = 0x1,
    avx2 = 0x2,
    avx512 = 0x3,
    neon = 0x1001
};

isa_lvl g_isaLevel = isa_lvl::none;
void init_arch(void);


// TODO: call this once on startup
void init_arch(void)
{
    #if defined(ARCH_ARM64)
        g_isaLevel = isa_lvl::neon; // ARM64 always supports NEON
    #elif defined(ARCH_X64)
        int regs[4];
        __cpuidex(regs, 7,0); // use cpuid instruction to interrogate the CPU
        if (regs[1] & (1 << 16)) {
            g_isaLevel = isa_lvl::avx512;
        } else if (regs[1] & (1 << 5)) {
            g_isaLevel = isa_lvl::avx2;
        } else {
            g_isaLevel = isa_lvl::sse2; // all x86-64 CPUs have sse2
        }
    #else
        // TODO: other archs
    #endif
}

Finally, you can use the cached ISA info at runtime to dispatch the best code path:
void do_stuff()
{
    switch (g_isaLevel)
    {
#if defined(ARCH_X64)
    case isa_lvl::sse2:
        do_stuff_sse2();
        break;
    case isa_lvl::avx2:
        do_stuff_avx2();
        break;
    //...
#elif defined(ARCH_ARM64)
    case isa_lvl::neon:
        do_stuff_neon();
        break;
#endif

    default:
        do_stuff_();
    }
}


Instead of ARCH_ARM64, I would use __ARM_NEON to detect NEON.
